# Python 3.2 with Tkinter with webbrowser - search program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-webbrowser

As the title suggests, I'm trying to create little search tool with GUI.
How I want it to work: When I click the button 'search', open 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=qr5cU8GJGMnStAao1YG4BA#q=' + key words that I want to search for. These key words I will type in.

Whole code:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

class MainClass():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.parent=master
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        self.Source=StringVar()
        #This next line I just tried out to use 'what' instead of 'str(self.Source) in def search(self)
        what=Entry(myGUI, textvariable=self.Source).grid(row=9, column=2) 

        label4=Label(myGUI, text='Key words:', fg= 'Black').grid(row=9, column=1)

        button4=Button(myGUI, text="  Search  ", command=self.search).grid(row=18, column=1)


    def search(self):
            webbrowser.open('http://google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=qr5cU8GJGMnStAao1YG4BA#q=' + str(self.Source.get))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    myGUI=Tk()
    app=MainClass(myGUI)
    myGUI.geometry("300x100+100+200")
    myGUI.title('Google search')
    myGUI.mainloop()
```

Well, the problem I am having is with this line:

```
def search(self):
        webbrowser.open('http://google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=qr5cU8GJGMnStAao1YG4BA#q=' + str(self.Source.get))
```

If I leave it as it is and click the search button, it opens google and searches for:
'bound method StringVar.get of tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0301EE90'

If I keep the line, but instead of str(self.Source.get) I use str(self.Source), it again opens the google, but this time it searches for: PY_VAR0

If I use just self.Source, it gives me an error "Can't convert 'StringVar' object to str implicitly" when I press the search button.

So I am a little confused how to correctly use this, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually call the get method  `self.Source.get()`, otherwise, what you are providing to `str` is the method, not its return value.

Thus, the whole line would be

```
webbrowser.open('http://google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=qr5cU8GJGMnStAao1YG4BA#q=' + str(self.Source.get()))
```

Comment: unbelievable, so simple, yet it worked! Thank you very much. I was expecting to my problem to be a little more complex, but just using self.Source.get() instead of just self.Source.get made the problem go away.